# Populate the "recipient" in an email submit form from php file

Tags: php, forms, email

What I have is a template site I am selling to users that I am using php files to easily change the info per user but just making a few changes in an includes folder. What I am trying to accomplish with it now it being able to change the "recipient" of the email submit form from the include file as such:

emailto.php = test@test.com

```
     <form id="ContactForm" action="send.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="emailto" value="?PHP require_once "includes/emailto.php"; ?">
          <div>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="bg">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="name">
              </div>
              Name: </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="bg">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="email">
              </div>
              Email: </div>
               <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="bg">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="phone">
              </div>
              Phone: </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="bg2">
                <textarea cols="1" rows="1" name="message"></textarea>
              </div>
              Message: </div>
               <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="bg">
               <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
              </div>
              I have read and understand the <a href="terms-and-conditions.php">Terms & Conditions.</a> </div>
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="go" value="Submit" /> </div>
        </form>
```

and here is the send.php file

```
 <?php 
 $emailto = $_POST['emailto'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $formcontent="From: $name \nEmail: $email \nPhone: $phone \nMessage: $message";
 $recipient = "$emailto";
 $subject = "Test Contact";
 $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
 mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
 header('Location: contact-us.php');
 ?>
```

I can't get it to work quite right with the php file. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PS: I am very green to coding, so I apologize if what Im trying to do is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do for this is create an include.php file where you can keep all the constant variables that change per site you sell.

so I would include my includes.php at the beginning of the page that needs the variable that will change per site sold and use the constant.

so if your includes.php was in your includes folder, at the top of the page

```
include 'include/includes.php';
```

In the includes.php file

```
define('EMAIL_TO','theuser@example.com');
```

in the form where you need the variable

```
<input type="hidden" name="emailto" value="<?php echo EMAIL_TO;?>">
```

This way you can define as many constants as you want and only have to make changes in one file and it will change everywhere on the site where the constants are used :)

Comment: Sorry for the newbie questions, but when I put include 'include/includes.php'; at the top of the contact-us.php page, it shows up on the page... what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: did you wrap it in php tags?

Comment: Like so... <?PHP include 'includes/includes.php'; ?>